# How to effectively use non null safe code with null safe dart code?

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, annotations, dart-null-safety

Is there any to way use a non-null safe code to a null safety code properly? For example, I have a function that returns a `null` value but it's not migrated to null safety. For example,

```
// @dart=2.9
User getUser(){
 if(loggedIn){
   return user;
 }
 return null
}
```

Now I want to call the above code in null safe code…

```
void build(){
 final user = getUser();
 if(user==null){
  return LoginScreen();
 }else{
  return HomeScreen();
 }
}
```

Now the linter says that `user == null` will always return false, assuming the user return by getUser() will always be non-null, but the issue is that `getUser()` is running inside the non-null safe code.

So whenever I run linter the LoginScreen widget is get removed and the whole logic falls apart.

Now I am not sure if we can fix the linter for this, but I think the better way is to handle annotation in IDE, how Kotlin does with java code. You mark the java function as @Nullable or @Nullable based on your function knowledge and then the Kotlin compiler or IDE takes care of this.

Do we have a way to do this dart? Because I am not able to find it anywhere.

One way to solve this would be to use [Null Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern), but since the codebase is 50% null safe code it would be hard to do everywhere, rather, I would rely on a tool for that.

Comment: Can't you migrate to null safety?

Comment: Not at the moment, because that code has dependencies on many other non-null safe codes.
And even If I can do it, let assumes someone can't then how would they do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do that

```
   // @dart=2.9
dynamic getUser(){
 if(loggedIn){
   return user;
 }
 return null
}
```

...

```
 void build(){
     final user = getUser();
     if(user is User){
      return LoginScreen();
     }else{
      return HomeScreen();
     }
    }
```